# How log serverless outputs to console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Consider serverless template:

```
service: my_application

frameworkVersion: ">=1.38.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1

resources:
  Resources:
    DataDeliveryRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Sid: ""
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - iot.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
        Path: "/"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: my_policy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                    - logs:PutMetricFilter
                    - logs:PutRetentionPolicy
                  Resource:
                    - "*"
```

Is there a way to log resource like `DataDeliveryRole` arn into console? Please note that resource name is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the created Role's ARN to the [`Outputs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) section of the CloudFormation template:

```
Resources:
  ...

Outputs:
  DataDeliveryRoleArn:
    Description: The ARN of the data delivery role
    Value: !GetAtt DataDeliveryRole.Arn
    Export:
      Name: DataDeliveryRoleArn
```

You can then query the output from the CloudFormation stack:

```
export ROLE_ARN=$(
    aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
      --stack-name YOUR_STACK_NAME --output text --region YOUR_REGION \
      --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='DataDeliveryRoleArn'].OutputValue" \
    )
echo $ROLE_ARN
```